# How to use JSON data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to javascript and therefore don't really know how to ask the question I'm trying to ask. The point of saying that is to apologize if this is a duplicate question. With that being said, I stumbled across [this site](http://timeline.knightlab.com/) and want to utilize the approach talked about [here](https://timeline3.knightlab.com/docs/instantiate-a-timeline.html). Given that my use cases for a tool like this will involve generating JSON dynamically with Python or R, I'd like to know how to

a) Generate the JSON appropriately.

b) Integrate that with a `<script>` tag to make it a JSON object in Javascipt.

Here is the code I have now:

```
html <- paste('<head><link title="timeline-styles", rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/css/timeline.css"><script src="//cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/js/timeline.js"></script></head><body><div id="timeline-embed" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div><script type="text/javascript">var timeline_json=', readr::read_lines("~/projects/timelineJS/trial.json") %>% paste(collapse=''),'; window.timeline=new TL.Timeline("timeline-embed", timeline_json);</script></body>', sep='')
write(html, file="~/projects/timelineJS/test.html")
```

The output appears to be what I'd want (the output below has been cleaned up):

```
<head>
  <link title="timeline-styles" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/css/timeline.css">
  <script src="//cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/js/timeline.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="timeline-embed" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var timeline_json={"title": {"media": {"url": "//www.flickr.com/photos/tm_10001/2310475988/", "caption": "Whitney Houston performing on her My Love is Your Love Tour in Hamburg.", "credit": "flickr/<a href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/tm_10001/'>tm_10001</a>"}, "text": {"headline": "Whitney Houston<br/> 1963 - 2012", "text": "<p>Houston's voice caught the imagination of the world propelling her to superstardom at an early age becoming one of the most awarded performers of our time. This is a look into the amazing heights she achieved and her personal struggles with substance abuse and a tumultuous marriage.</p>"}}, "events": ["media": {"url": "https://youtu.be/fSrO91XO1Ck", "caption": "", "credit": "<a href=\"http://unidiscmusic.com\">Unidisc Music</a>"}, "start_date": {"year": "1978"}, "text": {"headline": "First Recording", "text": "At the age of 15 Houston was featured on Michael Zager's song, Life's a Party."}]};
    window.timeline = new TL.Timeline("timeline-embed", timeline_json);
  </script>
</body>
```

However, when I load the html file, it's just a blank screen. I don't know what I'm doing well enough to know where to start debugging, so any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if you add some text in body part.. that too it will not display?

Comment: No, if I add `<p>This is a test</p>` it does display properly. And underneath the div as well, so the div is being generated, just not the content it seems.

Comment: The events need to be an array of objects so you need "events" : [{ ... }]. IOW you are missing the {} within this declaration.

Comment: @jeff - You nailed it! Please submit it as an answer so I can accept. Also, if you're up to the task of typing out an explanation about the difference between [...] and [{...}], I'd greatly appreciate it. Either way, thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events need to be an array of objects.

A normal array would only hold a single value i.e. `Days = [ "mon", "tues" .... }` .

An object can hold multiple pieces of information (even functions).

You need to tell JavaScript that you want to use an array[] and this array contains multiple objects {} so you end up with `[{},{},{},{}]`.

Using your previous code you are telling the JSON parser to expect an array. The parser looks up the value upto the : . Since this is not an array delimiter it causes the parser to throw an error

```
"events": [
  "media": {
     "url": "https://youtu.be/fSrO91XO1Ck", 
     "caption": "", 
     "credit": "<a href=\"http://unidiscmusic.com\">Unidisc Music</a>"
  }, 
  "start_date": {"year": "1978"}, 
  "text": {
     "headline": "First Recording", 
     "text": "At the age of 15 Houston was featured on Michael Zager's song, Life's a Party."
  }
]
```

This code tells the parse to expect an array [ the next symbol is for an object. So the parser will then expect an array of one or more objects.

```
"events": [{
  "media": {
     "url": "https://youtu.be/fSrO91XO1Ck", 
     "caption": "", 
     "credit": "<a href=\"http://unidiscmusic.com\">Unidisc Music</a>"
  }, 
  "start_date": {"year": "1978"}, 
  "text": {
     "headline": "First Recording", 
     "text": "At the age of 15 Houston was featured on Michael Zager's song, Life's a Party."
  }
}]
```

The parser if very fussy. If it finds a error then it will stop processing the data. Be sure to look at the browsers console log (F12 and console - in Chrome).

Comment: This gets the page to load in RStudio's Viewer Pane, but no in Mozilla Firefox. Looking at the console log, I'm getting a ReferenceError: TL is not defined. I posted a new question on SO if you care to save the day twice in one night: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709272/javascript-referenceerror-tl-not-defined-even-though-its-explicity-defined-in